# Cascaded shadow maps. Seams between cascades

Tags: opengl, shadow, shadow-mapping, mipmap

I implemented cascaded shadow maps, where shadow maps for each cascade is rendered to one canvas:[image]

The light projections for each cascade are calculated from the bounding spheres of camera sub-frustums:[image]

The code for calculation visibility value:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    v_shadowCoord[i] = u_lightVPshifted[i] * vec4(a_WolrdPosition, 1);
}

highp float zTocompare = v_shadowCoord[iCascade].z - bias;
return texture(u_shadowMap, vec3(v_shadowCoord[iCascade].xy, zTocompare));
```

where `v_shadowCoord` for first cascade are in `(0, 1), (0, 0.33)` ranges, for second `(0, 1), (0.33, 0.66)`, third `(0, 1), (0.66, 1)`.

**The problem** is that I get seams between cascades when anisotropic filtering is enabled. Here is the explanation of problem and suggested fix at the bottom of the page: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416307(v=vs.85).aspx)

As I understand, for cascade borders the wrong mipmap is selected - the smallest. Because the texels for two neighboring vertices on scene come from different cascades and therefore screen-space derivatives are large. I tried the suggested fix from the site, still have same seam:

```
highp vec2 uv = v_shadowCoord[iCascade].xy;
highp vec2 dx = dFdx (uv) / u_cascadeScales[iCascade];
highp vec2 dy = dFdy (uv) / u_cascadeScales[iCascade];
highp float zTocompare = (v_shadowCoord[iCascade].z) - bias;
return textureGradOffset(u_shadowMap, vec3(uv,  zTocompare), dx, dy, ivec2(0, 0));
```

I suppose I don't use the right input there. `v_shadowCoord` I described above, `u_cascadeScales` are scales of projection sizes in light view space relative to first one: I have `(1.0, 14.0, 300.0)`. Could you please explain how just scaling the derivatives will help selecting right mipmap and suggest what is wrong in the code? I expect that even with that scaling, values on the border will still be mapped to distant texels and wrong mipmap will be used.

Comment: Make sure you got clamp (vs wrap) texture address mode enabled when fetching from shadow map.

Comment: Besides what Jarkkol said, it's common to have a blend region between cascades. The blend region is more to hide the fact that the shadow map resolution changed, and would be more of a "cover up" of this seam than a proper fix, but FYI in case it helps!